# Ubuntu 22.0 LTS don't start Error F30

Tags: boot, software-installation, laptop, hp, startup

Error F30 when installing Ubuntu on HP g645 J1 laptop:
I'm trying to install Ubuntu on an old laptop. When I finish the installation and restart the device, the hard drive doesn't recognize the operating system.
I've tried booting in legacy and UEFI mode and switching hard drives.
I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: That looks like an HP error, not from Ubuntu. Do you have latest BIOS/UEFI from HP? Is system UEFI or BIOS as it looks like its from just about when Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode with release of Windows 8? Then are you trying to boot in correct mode. Most tools to create bootable flash drive, can be booted in either UEFi or BIOS mode, but then must match system setting for default boot mode.